# ImageViews inside relative layout overlapping

Tags: android, imageview

I'm loading a series of images (programaticaly) from a URL into a RelativeLayout, the problem is that they appear all overlaped in the same spot, how I could load the images one under each other?

Here is the part of the code:

```
RelativeLayout imageWrapper = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.image_wraper);

    try {
        for(int i=0; i<articuloClick.LlenarImagenes(posicion).getImagenesSrc().size(); i++){
            ImageView imagen=new ImageView(this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams vp = 
                    new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            imagen.setLayoutParams(vp);        
            imagen.setImageBitmap(run(articuloClick.LlenarImagenes(posicion).getImagenesSrc().get(i)));
            imageWrapper.addView(imagen);

        }
    } catch (IOException  e) {
        Log.e("Escepcion IO:", e.toString());
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        Log.e("Escepcion XMLPullParser:", e.toString());
    }
```

This is the xml (edited to be more readable):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:paddingTop="20dp"   android:paddingLeft="20dp"      android:paddingRight="20dp" android:paddingBottom="20dp"
android:background="#eeeeee"
android:id="@+id/art">     
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">       
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"   android:paddingLeft="10dp"  android:paddingRight="10dp" android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/borde">

      (...)

      <RelativeLayout 
            android:id="@+id/image_wraper"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is what I'm getting:

[image: Image from the device with 2 overlapped images]

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to change your `RelativeLayout` into a `LinearLayout` with `orientation="vertical"`

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/image_wraper"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Then in code:

```
LinearLayout imageWrapper = (LinearLayout ) findViewById(R.id.image_wraper);
```

Your images will appear one below the other.